# Can we merge the tag 'iconograpy' with 'icons'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [iconograpy](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iconograpy) is a typo and I noted that the tag [iconography](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iconography) redirects to [icons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icons).

Can we either delete the misspelled tag (only tagged to one post) or point it to icons?

edited to add: I re-tagged [the question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56679/iconography-for-verbatim-vs-paraphrase) that had originally been tagged with the typo, so really [iconograpy](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iconograpy) can just be deleted.

Comment: The tag'll get auto-deleted soon and new users can't re-create non-existing tags. Unless it proves to be a common typo I'm not sure there's anything else to be done.

Comment: Sounds good, didn't know there was auto-deletion of tags.  That's handy.